# Python string replace not working (bytes input expected?)

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, replace, byte

I am trying to use Pyner (https://github.com/dat/pyner) for NER. I give it a string of text to extract named entities from it. But I get an error. I am attaching the snipet where the error arises:

```
for s in ('\f', '\n', '\r', '\t', '\v'): #strip whitespaces
    text = text.replace(s, '')

Error message: {TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'}
```

This error occurs even when I try multiple types of inputs (bytes objects)

```
text = b'This'
text = bytes("This".encode('utf-8'))
```

I think the problem is that replace is not getting the right input type. I am using python 3.5. What am I doing wrong? Please help!

Comment: Are you trying to remove whitespace solely from the beginning and end?  Because there is a `strip` function that does just that.  If you're removing all whitespace, it should be noted that you're missing a space `' '`

Answer (score 8):

`replace` works with `str` or `bytes` but not both mixed.

You could rewrite it like this:

```
for s in (b'\f', b'\n', b'\r', b'\t', b'\v'): #strip whitespaces except space!
    text = text.replace(s, b'')
```

you could also to apply `strip` which works with `bytes` type:

```
text = text.strip()  # remove all of the above + space
```

Also possible: convert back to `str` beforehand, trying:

```
text = str(text)
```

or

```
text = text.decode('utf-8')
```

(choose the best solution to avoid modifying a third-party package, as Patrick noted)

Comment: This works for me. So I suppose the lines of code in the package should be modified to this. Thank you!

Comment: @SashaGreen it means that the package was designed to work with strings, but you're trying to make it work with bytes.  Be very careful before you make any changes.  If this package is necessary for what you're doing, you should make every attempt to change your inputs rather than someone elses code.