# How to remove specific elements in list of bytes like objects

Tags: python, list

For example I have a list with many strings in format of bytes objects:

```
ls = [b’\x9e\x9d\x9e\r’, b’\x9e\x9d\x9e\r’]
```

So I want to remove \r from this string to get:

```
ls = [b’\x9e\x9d\x9e’, b’\x9e\x9d\x9e’]
```

Is it possible to do that with this types of objects. If it would be a normal strings it would be not a problem. But with bytes I cannot get what I want.

Comment: *"Is it possible"* - Of course it is.

Comment: I guess you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41599579/python-string-replace-not-working-bytes-input-expected

Comment: Or rather it *would be*, if what you showed were valid Python.

Comment: `[x.replace(b'\r', b'') for x in ls]`. The method `replace` works for both byte or str, but the arguments must be bytes too if you want to replace bytes. Also note that you are using `’` to create strings, but you need to use `'` or `"` in python.

Comment: Thanks a lot guys. Now it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ls = [b’\x9e\x9d\x9e\r’, b’\x9e\x9d\x9e\r’]

l = [i.rstrip(b'\r') if i.endswith(b'\r') else i for i in ls ]
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
ls = [b'\x9e\x9d\x9e\r', b'\x9e\x9d\x9e\r']
ls = [old_byte[:-1] for old_byte in ls]
```

You can get the byte(s) you want by specifying the range of `bytes`.